# Similarity or Similarities

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference

As you know, the word "**[similarity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/similarity?q=Similarity%20)**" can be both countable and uncountable. Based on this matter and whereas you can easily find some results for each case surfing the net, I have no idea surfing the net, which sentence bellow sounds more idiomatic and natural. I am wondering which sentence is correct:

> 1- They are like apples and oranges; there **is no similarity** between their personalities. 
> 2- They are like apples and oranges; there **are no similarities** between their personalities.

Logically, #2 should be more idiomatic to me.

Comment: We usually say there's (singular) ***no difference*** in meaning, regardless of whether you use singular or plural in your examples referencing non-existent ***similarities***. But in some other contexts we nearly always use plural: *Because I have a cat, there **are no birds** in my garden* (not normally *...there **is no bird** in my garden*).

Comment: Personally, I think there's a difference between ***apples and oranges*** (which have *some* similarities; *inter alia*, they're both "round" fruits) and ***chalk and cheese*** (which are *totally* different in practically every way). We use ***apples and oranges*** (or ***apples and pears*** from "stairs") when pointing out that someone has made an inappropriate comparison between things which are too different to be "usefully" compared. But we use ***chalk and cheese*** to stress how *extremely* different two things are (they're so different it's unlikely *anyone* would try to compare them).

Comment: ...so the two "standard collocations" are along the lines of 1: *You're trying to **compare apples and oranges*** (inappropriate comparison) and 2: *They're **as different as chalk and cheese*** (as different as it's possible to be). You'll rarely if ever encounter the "opposite" versions 1b: *You're trying to **compare chalk and cheese*** and 2b: *They're **as different as apples and oranges***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't lean too heavily on logical decisions when dealing with English.

Both of your examples are well-written, and perfectly normal usage. To my mind, your first example, using the singular form, is more common, but only slightly, and is a perfect example of how you can rewrite one sentence into another form.

Comment: You might say it's "arbitrary", but I think there is some "logic" to the fact that OP's example isn't actually very idiomatic (regardless of the singular/plural difference). In *his* context it's usually ***chalk and cheese*** (totally different) as opposed to ***apples and oranges*** (not sufficiently similar to justify making some context-specific comparison between them).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I didn't say anything was 'arbitrary'.

Comment: ***One** might say it's "arbitrary"*, then. But how else should we interpret your first sentence? Note that I didn't say there was necessarily any "logic" involved in choosing singular ***similarity*** or plural  ***similarities*** in OP's context (I still haven't bothered to think that one through). The point I was making was simply that idiomatically speaking, OP should have used ***chalk and cheese*** rather than ***apples and oranges*** - and the reason for that is actually quite "logical", as well as being idiomatically well-established.